# Writing Array To $scope (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm modifying the Altair Material Design Template (http://themeforest.net/item/altair-admin-material-design-premium-template/12190654) & have the following Angular JS controller.

I am successfully calling an API & creating variables in the for loop.  I want to then write them to $scope.dragulaItems.  This seems to work fine in the console log, however the array is not displaying properly on the page.

The html div is as follows:

```
            <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-small-1-2 uk-grid-width-medium-1-3 uk-grid-width-large-1-5" data-uk-grid-margin dragula='"first-dragula"' dragula-model='dragulaItems'>
            <div ng-repeat="item in dragulaItems">
```

I am seeing the correct number of returns in the response on the page (20 styled divs), but no content within them.

```
angular
.module('altairApp',[angularDragula(angular)])
.controller('addResultsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'utils',

    function ($scope,$rootScope,utils) {

        // Search

        SessionKey = "YXZmLwmNiT3vTuXwbbQrSY8ibrGhLuWLZag3DCCH2zu7w9dO3b";

        $("#addSearch").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchTerm = $("#addSearch-term").val();
            var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": "https://secure.techfor.com/labsapi/restservice.aspx?command=PRODUCTSEARCH&searchtext="+searchTerm+"&extendedinfo=n&page=1&sessionkey="+SessionKey+"",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
              }
            }
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                //console.log(response);
                $("#searchTerm").html(searchTerm);
                $scope.dragulaItems = [];
                for (i in response.Products) {
                    var name = response.Products[i].Name;
                    var imagePath = response.Products[i].ImagePath;
                    var EAN = response.Products[i].EANBarcode;
                    var price = response.Products[i].Price;
                    var offer = response.Products[i].OfferPromotion;
                    var offerValid = response.Products[i].OfferValidity;
                    $scope.dragulaItems.push ("{\"Name\": \""+name+"\",\"Price\": \""+price+"\",\"EANBarcode\": \""+EAN+"\",\"ImagePath\": \""+imagePath+"\",\"OfferPromotion\": \""+offer+"\",\"OfferValidity\": \""+offerValid+"\"}");
                }
                console.log($scope.dragulaItems); 
            });

        });

    }
```

]);

If I manually change the $scope.dragulaItems = []; to say:

```
$scope.dragulaItems = [
{"Name":"Bob"},
{"Name":"Reggie"}
];
```

I get a return of 2 items with the Name field correctly displayed.  I am confused as clearly the fact that there are 20 items in the array is getting through, but the content within them is not.

Comment: Do not use `for ... in` for iterating through arrays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding items to the array the wrong way. You need to create a javascript object and set the different property values like `Name` and `Price` etc and push that object to your array.

Try this.

```
for (var i in response.Products) {

  var name = response.Products[i].Name;
  var price = response.Products[i].Price;
  var eanBarCode= response.Products[i].EANBarcode;

  var item = { Name : name , Price : price, EANBarcode: eanBarCode };
  $scope.dragulaItems.push(item);

}
```

Or you may use [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) for looping.

```
angular.forEach(response.Products, function(value, key) {

  var name = value.Name;
  var price = value.Price;
  var eanBarCode = value.EANBarcode;

  var item = { Name : name , Price : price, EANBarcode: eanBarCode };
  $scope.dragulaItems.push(item);

});
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew it was simple. There goes a wasted evening!

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the wrong items into the array.

You have to push *objects* into the array, not strings which are displayed like objects:

```
for (i in response.Products) {
  var data = {};
  data.Name = response.Products[i].Name;
  data.ImagePath = response.Products[i].ImagePath;
  data.EAN = response.Products[i].EANBarcode;
  data.Price = response.Products[i].Price;
  data.Offer = response.Products[i].OfferPromotion;
  data.OfferValid = response.Products[i].OfferValidity;
  $scope.dragulaItems.push (data);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  The data object returns as data {}

Comment: `data` would be `{}` outside the scope of the `for` loop, but it should work inside the for loop.